# Would this line of code be vulnerable to a SQLI attack?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm currently messing around with my friend's code (he gave me 100% authority to test his web applications for fun) and I discovered a vulnerabiliy that allowed me to view some segments of his code. However, upon attempting to exploit using various fuzzing/manual testing techinques I am unable to get a verbose error nor able to bypass authentication using the query. I've tried to exploit this using sqlmap through the --cookie="" flag to no success however.

I am aware that the $token variable is not wrapped between '' and therefore I thought I could add the following: 1 OR 1=1 "-- (which did not work)

So far I have only been able to get a mysqli_result object as a return:

```
    mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 5
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 0
    [type] => 0
)
//which, by the way, changes values depending upon what I input/fuzz.

    <?php

include_once("mysql.php");

$ck = $_COOKIES;
if(isset($ck["session"])){
  $token = $ck['session'];
  $conn->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE token=$token AND loggedin=1");
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header("Location: account.php");
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, it would. Parameterize.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that line of code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

If you are asking for a pattern that will expose the vulnerability, consider just supplying the string `'token'`.

Then the generated SQL would be:

```
 SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE token=token AND loggedin=1
```

Or, include a `1 OR 1=1 --`, with the `--` to start a comment, so the query could be:

```
 SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE token=1 OR 1=1 -- AND loggedin=1
```

--

As far as further exploiting that vulnerability, the hackers have tools that help them quickly figure it out.

We don't need to spend time delving into that. Just fix the vulnerability by refactoring the code to use a *prepared statement* with a *bind placeholder*.

And if this is vulnerable, very likely that this same developer has left bloatloads of SQL Injection vulnerabilities in his wake, all over the code. All of the code will need remediation.